# Why can I use number 1 in Taylor series arctan?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Why can I use number 1 in Taylor series arctan?
Taylor serie arctan:
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: Do you mean: why can $x$ be $1$?  If so because that is within its radius of convergence.

Comment: @badjohn It's on the boundary.  Convergence is not guaranteed.

Comment: @saulspatz Good point.  I guess that I should have said: it's known to converge for $1$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can, because:

- By the alternating series test, that series converges when $x=1$.
- By [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem),$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}=\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{2n+1}.$$